# Error compiling C++ file using g++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, prng

I am using g++ from cygwin, I am trying to compile a .cpp file but I am encountering an error,

here is the code:

```
#include "randomc.h"
#include <time.h>             // Define time() 
#include <stdio.h>            // Define printf() 
#include <cstdlib>



int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
int seed = atoi(argv[1]);
int looptotal = atoi(argv[2]);

//initializes rng, I want to use argv[1] to set seed 
void CRandomMother::RandomInit (int seed) {
int i;
// loop for the amount of times set by looptotal and return random number
for (i = 0; i < looptotal; i++) {
double s;
s = Random();
printf("\n%f", s)
}

}
return 0;

}
```

Here is the error I am getting when trying to compile using cygwin terminal and g++

```
Administrator@WIN-19CEL322IRP /cygdrive/c/xampp/xampp/htdocs$  g++ ar.cpp -o prog
ar.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
ar.cpp:13: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
ar.cpp:13: error: expected `,' or `;' before '{' token
```

the .cpp file, and the header file randomc.h, are located in my xampp location. I don't think this should matter at all, should it? Can someone tell me how I can get this to compile and run please? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to define `CRandomMother::RandomInit` inside `main` ?

Comment: you need to really learn the basic C++ syntax before trying anything bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, after today I'm going to learn more about C++. I guess its because I started off with php I am not used to change easily.

Answer (score 8):

Move the function definition outside `main`:

```
//initializes rng, I want to use argv[1] to set seed 
void CRandomMother::RandomInit (int seed, int looptotal) {
   int i;
   // loop for the amount of times set by looptotal and return random number
   for (i = 0; i < looptotal; i++) {
      double s;
      s = Random();
      printf("\n%f", s)
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int seed = atoi(argv[1]);
   int looptotal = atoi(argv[2]);
   return 0;
}
```

The error message seems pretty clear to me.

In C++ you're not allowed to define functions inside another function.

Comment: +1 from me, but you need to be able to see looptotal from RandomInit, and maybe also call RandomInit ;)

Comment: Of course, you'll probably need to add "looptotal" as an argument to the function, and I'm guessing you probably also want to actually call it.

Comment: But I am having a problem trying to compile your corrected code


    Administrator@WIN-19CEL322IRP /cygdrive/c/xampp/xampp/htdocs
    $ g++ ar.cpp -o prog
    ar.cpp: In member function `void      CRandomMother::RandomInit(int)':
    ar.cpp:12: error: `looptotal' undeclared (first use this     function)
    ar.cpp:12: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only     once for each function it appears in.)
    ar.cpp:16: error: expected `;' before '}' token

   Administrator@WIN-19CEL322IRP /cygdrive/c/xampp/xampp/htdocs
   $

Comment: Ok I managed to fix that, but now I have another problem
$ g++ ar.cpp -o prog
/tmp/ccYvWSSD.o:ar.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `CRandomMother::Random()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Administrator@WIN-19CEL322IRP /cygdrive/c/xampp/xampp/htdocs
$

is there an issue? Here is the class information in the header file

Comment: class CRandomMother {                  // Encapsulate random number generator
public:
   void RandomInit(int seed);          // Initialization
   int IRandom(int min, int max);      // Get integer random number in desired interval
   double Random();                    // Get floating point random number
   uint32_t BRandom();                 // Output random bits
   CRandomMother(int seed) {           // Constructor
      RandomInit(seed);}
protected:
   uint32_t x[5];                      // History buffer
};

Comment: @RichardWilliam: Have you provided implementation for CRandomMother ::Random function?

Comment: How would I go about implementing that? I have been looking on Google :S but I still do not understand this old object oriented approach to things, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to use method Random();?